# Shared Preferences. Как мне реализовать загрузку и запись на облако?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, android-shared-preferences

Я делаю прогу на андроид. И в ней сохранение данных идёт с помощью Shared Preferences. Мне нужно загружать эти данные с и на облако. Я пробовал Firebase, но Build Tools 3.1.4 просто не ставится. И использовать firebase я не могу. Как мне реализовать загрузку и запись на облако? Используя тот же самый Shared Preferences.

Comment: SharedPreferences предназначены для хранения состояний (настроек) а не данных. используйте для хранения данных БД, как Room Realm и тп.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase отлично работает. Если есть трудности с подключением, то возможно документация поможет. Как еще один вариант - использовать Amazon-сервисы. Сохранение данных - посмотрите в сторону [Realm](https://realm.io/products/realm-database/), у них есть и облачное решение. Shared Preferences используйте только для локальных сохранений.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю что Firebase наиболее простое решение, проще только из твоей программы вызвать активити Google Drive или Яндекс Диска, что бы уже программа гугл(яндекс)диска сделала необходимые манипуляции с файлом.
 Другой подход работать с API облачных сервисов, например у яндекса([документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/disk/doc/dg/sdk/java-docpage/)).